# wrong parsing of JSON: innadecuate truncation of string

Tags: r, json

When trying to read a JSON file with a string that contains \u0000, the string gets truncated.

For example, if the contents of the JSON file are:

```
{
  "s1": "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n\r\nPK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0006\u0000",
  "s2": "aeiou"
}
```

"s1" gets truncated:

```
> jsonlite::fromJSON("test.json")
$s1
[1] "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n\r\nPK\003\004\024"

$s2
[1] "aeiou"
```

This happens with the most relevant packages: jsonlite, rjson, ndjson, tidyjson...
(And doesn't happen on JS, nor Python libraries.)

It would be desirable to get a warning: "Embedded nul in string".
And also finding a library (equivalent to `iotools::read.csv.raw` for csv) that could read those strings as raw.

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: The string s1 should be "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n\r\nPK\003\004\024\000\006\000".